# Modify MySQL query to also show child records sorted under parent records in a menu

Tags: php, mysql, sql, sql-order-by

I need to build a MySQL database driven Link menu that only shows links that a user has permission to view.

The link menu will also have `parent` and `child` links.  Child links will be under parent links (like a directory structure).

I have 2 database tables shown below.  `intranet_links` which has the link records and `user_link_permissions` which has the permissions to determine if the user can view the link or not.

Here is my current SQL query which returns only the Links a user has permission to view...

Also here is a working demo to see the results http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/8aa75/2

```
SELECT intranet_links.id,
       intranet_links.title,
       intranet_links.url,
       intranet_links.description,
       intranet_links.sort_order,
       intranet_links.parent,
       user_link_permissions.user_id
FROM user_link_permissions
JOIN intranet_links ON user_link_permissions.link_id=intranet_links.id AND user_link_permissions.permission=1
WHERE user_link_permissions.permission=1
AND user_link_permissions.user_id=1
ORDER BY title
```

I need help to get my results to sort in a way that will let child links be ordered under parent links.

I am using PHP so it doesn't have to be all SQL.  My desird end result will be a menu like this...

[image]

---

**Database structure and data...**

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `intranet_links` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `title` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `description` text NOT NULL,
  `url` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `active` int(2) NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
  `sort_order` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `parent` int(10) NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `id` (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=8 ;

--
-- Dumping data for table `intranet_links`
--
INSERT INTO `intranet_links` (`id`, `title`, `description`, `url`, `active`, `sort_order`, `parent`) VALUES
('1', 'Lnk Parent 1', '', 'google.com', 1, NULL, 0),
('2', 'ink 2', '', 'google.com', 1, NULL, 0),
('3', 'link 3', '', 'google.com', 1, NULL, 0),
('4', 'Lnk Parent 2', '', 'google.com', 1, NULL, 0),
('5', 'ink 5', '', 'google.com', 1, NULL, 2),
('6', 'link 6', '', 'google.com', 1, NULL, 2),
('7', 'ink 7', '', 'google.com', 1, NULL, 2),
('8', 'link 8', '', 'google.com', 1, NULL, 2);



CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `user_link_permissions` (
  `id` int(100) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `user_id` int(30) NOT NULL,
  `link_id` int(30) NOT NULL,
  `permission` int(2) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  KEY `id` (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=8 ;

--
-- Dumping data for table `user_link_permissions`
--
INSERT INTO `user_link_permissions` (`id`, `user_id`, `link_id`, `permission`) VALUES
(1, 1, 1, 1),
(2, 1, 2, 1),
(3, 1, 3, 0),
(4, 1, 4, 1),
(5, 1, 5, 1),
(6, 1, 6, 0),
(7, 1, 7, 1),
(8, 1, 8, 1),
(9, 2, 1, 1),
(10, 2, 2, 1),
(11, 2, 3, 1),
(12, 2, 4, 1),
(13, 2, 5, 1),
(14, 2, 6, 1),
(15, 2, 7, 1),
(16, 2, 8, 1);
```

Answer (score 2):

I think your best best is to break it up into two queries. So first query for all of the link_ids that the user has permission to see.

```
SELECT link_id FROM user_link_permissions WHERE user_id=:user AND permission=1
```

Then with the result of that query, do a second query to actually get the links and order them however you want

```
SELECT * FROM intranet_links WHERE id IN (123, 456, 789) ORDER BY title
```

You could do it just as easily with a subquery, but I prefer and have had great success with breaking SQL up into smaller pieces.

Comment: As far as the grouping and sorting of child under parent... I'd handle that logic on the application side. Not MySql side.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using 1 SQL Query.

Below is my working code, using PHP's Laravel Framework...

**Menu Features:**

- User Link page where only links that a user has permissions to view are shown.
- User link page also shows menus in a Parent and child folder like structure.
- Admin page to save user permission settings for each link on each user.
- Admin page uses AJAX to instantly save the permission settings as soon as you click a checkbox on any setting.
- Checkbox that will mass check/un-check all checkboxes for a particular user.

**Controller PHP with MySQL Query:**

```
public function buildMultiLevelPermissionBasedMenu()
{

    $linksQuery = DB::table('user_link_permissions')
        ->select(DB::raw('intranet_links.id,
           intranet_links.title,
           intranet_links.url,
           intranet_links.description,
           intranet_links.sort_order,
           intranet_links.parent,
           user_link_permissions.user_id'))
        ->leftJoin('intranet_links', function($leftJoin)
        {
            $leftJoin->on('user_link_permissions.link_id', '=', 'intranet_links.id');
        })
        ->where('user_link_permissions.permission', 1)
        ->where('user_link_permissions.user_id', Auth::user()->user_id)
        ->orderBy('parent', 'asc')
        ->get();

        $links_array2 = array();

        foreach ($linksQuery as $link)
        {
            if($link->parent && array_key_exists($link->parent, $links_array2)){
                $links_array2[$link->parent]->sub_categories[]  = $link;
            }else{
                $links_array2[$link->id] = $link;
            }
        }

    return View::make('user/dashboard', array('links_array2' => $links_array2));
}
```

---

**then in my View I have...**

```
<div id="tree">
     <ul>
          @foreach($links_array2 as $link)

          <li class="expanded folder">{{ $link->title }}
                <?php
                if(isset($link->sub_categories)){
                    echo '<ul>';
                    foreach($link->sub_categories as $child_link){
                        echo '<li><a href="'.$child_link->url.'" target="_blank">'.$child_link->title.'</a></li>';
                    }
                    echo '</ul>';
                }
                ?>
          </li>
          @endforeach
      </ul>
</div>
```

---

**The final product:**

[image]

---

**Admin side to set Viewing Permission Per-User, Per-Link...**

[View full size image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OkAzG.png)
[image]